# Как правильно перехватывать системные вызовы в ядре linux 5.15 и выше

Tags: linux, c, системное-программирование, ядро

Как правильно перехватывать системные вызовы в ядре linux 5.15 и выше? Я нашел [статью](https://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/intercept_lnx.txt.html), но как я понимаю она уже не актуальна. По крайней мере константы на номера вызовов в sys_call_tabl точно не в файле `#include <sys/syscall.h>` потому что такого файла нет. Можно ли теперь перехватить системный вызов с помощью подмены указателей в sys_call_table, или есть другой более современный способ? буду рад примерам

Comment: Я не знаю откуда этот файл должен браться, но по крайней мере в моём Arch Linux он вполне существует и принадлежит пакету glibc

Comment: как я понимаю, glibc нельзя юзать в пространстве ядра((

Comment: статья устарела, `sys_call_tabl` ныне не является публичным... в гугле по запросу «linux syscall hook» есть несколько вариантов, как его можно найти, но если это не учебная задача, и не какая-то малварь, то это, скорей всего, не то, чем ты хочешь заниматься...